# Comparison operators for Symbols

Tags: julia, symbols, comparison-operators

In Julia, is it always the case that `:a < :b` evaluates to `true`?

More generally, can I rely on the relational operators (ie `<`, `>`, `==`, `<=`, `>=`) behaving for symbols in *exactly* the same way they do for strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The source code [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/4ba21aa57f57b9e42eeba5886d9dec772281e9f2/base/strings/basic.jl#L158-L159) shows that Julia uses C function `strcmp` to do the comparison:

```
cmp(a::String, b::String) = lexcmp(a.data, b.data)
cmp(a::Symbol, b::Symbol) = Int(sign(ccall(:strcmp, Int32, (Cstring, Cstring), a, b)))
```